# sonar report of Javascript/AngularJS application showing zero unit test success

Tags: javascript

Here is my sonar properties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=Client
sonar.projectNameClient
sonar.projectVersion=1
sonar.sources=src
sonar.language=js
sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath=reports/
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=reports/lcov.info
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I am getting Unit test coverage, but the unit test success shows 0 tests.

My source files and test files are in the same folder (src). Is that an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version of Sonar Javascript Plugin you are using, but the feature of importing javascript unit tests report was removed since version 1.5 (See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJS-163) and then was re-added on version 2.2 (See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJS-239), although it was not yet released.